# Specify custom include directory for library in rosmake (CMakeLists.txt)

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, ros

For a ROS project, I need Boost 1.55, which is currently incompatible for use with ROS, so I can not install it alongside ROS. Since compiling ROS from source is not an option, I would like to change the directory where the compiler looks for Boost (instead of `/usr/include/boost` just my own directory).

So, if I have `#include<boost/somefile.hpp>`, I would like it to in fact include `[package_folder]/include/boost/somefile.hpp`; and this must of course also go for all the `#include`'s in the Boost library itself. Is there an easy way of doing this (I think it should be done in the `CMakeLists.txt` file)

Here's what I tried (including what @ruslo suggested)

```
set(BOOST_ROOT include/boost_1_55_0)
find_package(Boost 1.55.0)
```

The boost status variables indicate that that went well, but then I still get

```
fatal error: boost/graph/successive_shortest_path_nonnegative_weights.hpp: No such file or directory
```

So, I listed all cmake variables that pointed to `/usr/include/` and appended my Boost location:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_IMPLICIT_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include;/usr/include)
set(CMAKE_C_IMPLICIT_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include;/usr/include)
set(GTEST_INCLUDE_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include;/usr/include)
```

But to no avail. How do I get `rosmake` to get my directory?

Comment: `set(BOOST_ROOT include/boost_1_55_0)` you need to set full path here

Comment: use `find_package(Boost 1.55.0 REQUIRED)` if boost is mandatory library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was easy. Added in CMakeLists.txt:

```
rosbuild_add_compile_flags(SingleImage "-std=c++0x")

include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/boost_1_55_0)
```

Which obviously I tried before, but that didn't work due to a 'dirty' build directory. So, always use `rosmake yourpackage --target=clean`... learned that the hard way.

Answer (score 1):

Just change [BOOST_ROOT](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#module%3aFindBoost) variable:

> cmake -DBOOST_ROOT=/your/boost/location ...other options...

Comment: Yeah that didn't work. I'll edit my question to include what I tried